# Console.log(arr) works but Console.log(arr[0]) logs undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a program that reads some data from my disk and converts it into an array of objects. When logging the array mentioned earlier, it is okay. But if I try to log or access a specific element in the array, undefined is logged instead. Here is my code:

```
  const [studies, setStudies] = useState<Study[]>();
  const [cameraStations, setCameraStations] = useState<CameraStation[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const tempStudyArr: Study[] = [];
    const tempCameraArr: CameraStation[] = [];

    const studiesPromise = Promise.resolve(getStudies());
    studiesPromise.then((value) => value.forEach((item) => {
      tempStudyArr.push(item);
      const cam = Promise.resolve(getCameraStations(item))
      cam.then((value) => value.forEach((v) => {
        tempCameraArr.push(v);
      }))
    }));
    
    setCameraStations(tempCameraArr);
    setStudies(tempStudyArr);
  }, [])

  if (studies == undefined) return null;
  if (cameraStations == undefined) return null;
  if (studies[0] == undefined) return null;

  console.log(studies[0])
  console.log(cameraStations) 
  console.log(cameraStations[0]) //<----- Ouputs "undefined"
```

getCameraStations and getStudies are defined like this:

```
async function getCameraStations(study: Study) {
  return await window.datastore.getCameraStations(study);
}

async function getStudies() {
  return await window.datastore.getStudies();
}
```

This is the output from the console:

[image: Console Ouput]

**EDIT:**
Some users linked similar questions related to console.log, and now I understand why undefined is being logged. Now my question is how do I index into that variable at all? If I put

`if (cameraStations[0] == undefined) return null;`

before the console.log, the component never renders and always returns null. If I pass the cameraStations array into a function, that function also says that the contents are undefined. How do I wait for the data inside the cameraStations array to be filled before interacting with it?

**SOLUTION EDIT**
Fixed my issue by creating and using an async function inside the useEffect to get the data. See below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const studiesList = await window.datastore.getStudies();

      const stations: CameraStation[][] = await Promise.all(
        studiesList.map(async (study) => {
          const cameras = await window.datastore.getCameraStations(study);
          return cameras
        })
      );

      setStudies(studiesList);
      setCameraStations(stations);
    }
    getData().catch(console.error);
  }, [])
```

Comment: the console is showing live data, and is updated as that data is changed. Your method to get data is asynchronous - you're trying to log it before its been read.

Comment: Output `Array(0)` sounds like an empty array, that's why index 0 is undefined

Comment: Regarding your edit: You'd generally use something like `cameraStations?.length` to check that the array exists and has content.

Comment: @DBS the issue with that is it always evaluates to 0. I can't seem to "wait" for the element to be populated.